# django save a value for unchecked checkbox

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

**//mytemplate//**

```
  <tr>
      <td><input  type="text" name="language1" id="language1" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="read1" id="read1" value="yes" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="write1" id="write1" value="yes" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="speak1" id="speak1" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input  type="text" name="language1" id="language1" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="read1" id="read1" value="yes" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="write1" id="write1" value="yes" /></td>
      <td><input  type="checkbox" name="speak1" id="speak1" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
```

I wanted to save yes into my db if the checkbox is checked,

If the checkbox was unchecked i want to save no into db,..

How to do it?

**EDIT**

```
def edit_other_info(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        user = request.POST.get('user_id')

        language1 = request.POST.get('language1')
        read1 = request.POST.get('read1')
        write1 = request.POST.get('write1')
        speak1 = request.POST.get('speak1')

        language2 = request.POST.get('language2')
        read2 = request.POST.get('read2')
        write2 = request.POST.get('write2')
        speak2 = request.POST.get('speak2')
        p=language(user_id=user,language1=language1,read1=read1,write1=write1,
        speak1=speak1,language2=language2,read2=read2,write2=write2,speak2=speak2)
        p.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/Profile/')
    else:

        details1 = language.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        return render_to_response('registration/language.html', {"details":details, "details1":details1}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you already done some Python code? I'd gladly see that too if so!

Answer (score 4):

If you provide a common name to all checkboxes you could retrive the value using

```
options = request.POST.getlist('name')
```

if nothing is checked, it returns a null list.

Answer (score 3):

Test if the checkbox id is in the post parameters like so:

```
def myview(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      read1_val = "read1" in request.POST
      MyModel(read1=read1_val).save()
```

If it is in there it was "yes". If it is not in there it was "no".

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223149/django-post-checkbox-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470833/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-django) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417127/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-all-selected-checkboxes-in-a-django-request-post)