# Django - How to post all those checkbox ID's which are unchecked as well to views

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, python-2.7

I have a table ( 7X4 ). First column of a table is checkbox. With the below code, I can get all the checked items in the UI to views, but I wanted to get unchecked ID's as well.

Below is my templates file:

```
<table id="tableForm" name="table-data" class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Week Day</th>
                            <th>Timing</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            {% for row in days_data %}

                            <tr>
                                <td id="{{row.id}}"><input value="{{row.set_name}}" name="checks" type="checkbox"></td>
                                <td> {{row.day}} </td>
                                <td>{{row.set_name}}</td>
                                <td>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

views.py file

```
def weekDays_set(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST.get('form_year')
        batch = request.POST.get('form_batch')
        days = request.POST.getlist('table-data')
        days1 = request.POST.getlist('checks')
        print(days1) # I am getting only checked rows ID's
```

I can get only checked row ID's in dictionary,  Can someone help me on getting unchecked rows data as well please ?

Comment: see this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147009/django-save-a-value-for-unchecked-checkbox/16168840

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I have followed the links provided and it worked.